# How to locally increase the size of indices?

Tags: math-mode

I have a problem with the size of my indices when using underbraces. It seems that if I use underbraces on all the indices, TeX automatically increases the index size:

[image]

When the underbraces don't cover all indices, TeX leaves the size of the indices unaltered, resulting in some unwanted space between the indices:

[image]

My code for the first picture is

```
\g_{\big\langle\underbrace{1\dots1}_{2i}\underbrace{2\dots2}_\text{$2k-2i$}\underbrace{3\dots3}_\text{$2j$}\underbrace{4\dots4}_\text{$2r-2j$}\big\rangle}
```

and for the second picture

```
\g_{11\underbrace{\scriptstyle 33\dots33}_\text{$2\alpha$}\underbrace{\scriptstyle 11\dots 11}_\text{$\l-2-2\alpha$}}+\g_{2233\dots3311\dots11}+\g_{3333\dots3311\dots11}+\g_{4433\dots3311\dots11}=0
```

(`\g` is something I have defined)

My question is: Does anyone know how to locally increase the size of indices. I want the indices in the second picture to have the same size as the first picture. For the rest of my document I still need the indices to have their original size so I'm looking to enlarge them locally but not in the rest of my document.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, can you post a minimal complete code (and not a fragment) in tex.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default style in which a piece of math is typeset:

`\textstyle`: apply the style used for mathematics typeset in paragraphs,

`\displaystyle`: apply the style used for mathematics typeset on lines by themselves,

`\scriptstyle`: apply the style used for subscripts or superscripts,

`\scriptscriptstyle`: apply the style used for second-order subscripts or superscripts,

They will remain in effect until the end of the math mode or the braced group, or until another style is selected.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\g}{\mathbf{g}}
    
\[  
\g_{\big\langle\underbrace{1\dots1}_{2i}
\underbrace{2\dots2}_{2k\enspace 2i}
\underbrace{3\dots3}_{2j}
\underbrace{4\dots4}_{2r\enspace 2j}
\big\rangle}
\]

\bigskip    

\[  
\g_{\displaystyle 11{\underbrace{33\dots33}_{\scriptscriptstyle 2\alpha}} \underbrace{11\dots 11}_{\scriptscriptstyle l-2-2\alpha}}
+ \g_{\displaystyle 2233\dots3311\dots11} + \g_{\displaystyle 3333\dots3311\dots11}  
\]
    
\end{document}
```